# Two nodes between same line in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

There is a way to write this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)--(10,0) node[midway,above] {top};
    \draw (0,0)--(10,0) node[midway,below] {bottom};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

drawing **only one line**?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: i've update it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 12):

This may be a duplicate, but you can just write multiple nodes after the line:

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (10,0) node[midway,above] {top} node[midway,below] {bottom};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image: result]

Answer (score 9):

This is actually example from Ti*k*Z & PGF manual ... you can use `quotes` library

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] (0,0) --  node[above] {top} node[below] {bottom} (10,0);
%
  \draw[red]  (0,2) to ["top", "bottom" '] (10,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]